# How to style a WordPress cusom field? (Wordpress User Front End Pro)

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to add custom css to edit the download link that is generated with a wordpress custom field.

The plugin is WP Front End Pro.

Here is what the page looks like now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j2pO.png

Here is the backend of the form creator:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaMKQ.png

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: If you are unclear of what I am asking just ask :)

Comment: So the downloadbutton class doesn't work?

Comment: Where would I put the css?

Comment: Here is what i did and it still does not work? http://i.imgur.com/vj5vt6f.png

Comment: I need to see your live site.

Comment: http://unturneduniverse.com/upload/26

Comment: so you want to know what CSS to use to target the link in "Map Download: 141696962955478"?

Comment: Yes, That is exactly right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actual look at your back-end, it is hard to tell how to add a custom CSS class to the download link. But you can style the link by other means. On this page, you can do

```
ul.wpuf_customs li>a{your style}
```

Comment: I will give you back-end access if that will help ;)

Comment: It worked after putting it in the theme's "custom css"